# Cannot access object-data in a nested object

Tags: vue.js

```
data() {
    return {
      perPage:2,
      swiperOption: {
        slidesPerView: perPage,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      },
    }
},
```

i just want to access perPage prop into swiperOption object

pls help me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly assign a data property which is not declared. Instead you can set perPage to swiperOption in created hook

**just add a created hook**

```
data() {
    return {
        perPage:2,
        swiperOption: {
            slidesPerView: 0,
            loop: true,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        },
    } 
}, 

created() {
    this.swiperOption.slidesPerView = this.perPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access an object's property *while* declaring it, but since `data` is a function you can just assign `perPage` to a variable:

```
data(){
    var perPage = 2;

    return {
      perPage:perPage,
      swiperOption: {
        slidesPerView: perPage,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `perPage` a constant or it will change depending on something?
If it's a constant, there is no need to declare it inside `data()`.

But if it changes, one way to do that is **setting a watcher on it** and update swiperOption with the new value everytime it changes. Something like:

```js
watch(){
   perPage(newVal){
      this.swiperOption.slidesPerView = newVal;
   }
}
```